# How can I open a .npy file that I downloaded from Github?

Tags: python

I just downloaded a .npy file in Github. But I can't open it. I tried the function "np.loadtxt()", but it didn't work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you using python then try with this. For example your file is **npyfile.npy**

```
import numpy as np
data = np.load('npyfile.npy')
print(data)
```